# Creating Sites & Sector Pie for Mapinfo using Python

Tags: python, geospatial, pyqgis, mapinfo

I'm trying to create sites using lat/long or easting/northing; however, when creating using Python it doesn't make the Pie correctly and sometimes the code fails totally. Can someone please guide me how can I make it using Python? Below is the code I used.

````
```
def create_sector_pie(row):
try:
    azimuth = row['AZIMUTH']
    beamwidth = row['BW']
    radius = row['Radius']

    # Calculate sector angles
    start_angle = azimuth - beamwidth / 2
    end_angle = azimuth + beamwidth / 2

    # Create a sector polygon as a pie shape
    center = (row['EASTING'], row['NORTHING'])  # Use Easting and 
Northing
    polygon_coords = [(center[0], center[1])]
    angle_step = radians(0.5)  # Increase this value for less 
detailed sectors
    for angle in np.arange(start_angle, end_angle, angle_step):
        x = center[0] + radius * cos(angle)
        y = center[1] + radius * sin(angle)
        polygon_coords.append((x, y))
    polygon_coords.append((center[0], center[1]))  # Close the 
polygon

    # Create a sector polygon
    polygon = Polygon(polygon_coords)
    
    # Smaller angle step
    angle_step = radians(0.5)

    # Buffer
    polygon = polygon.buffer(0.001)

    # Simplify
    polygon = polygon.simplify(tolerance=0.001)

    # Increase radius
    radius = radius * 3  
    
    if not polygon.is_valid:
        polygon = polygon.buffer(0)
    return polygon
except Exception as e:
    # Print the error and the row causing the issue for debugging
    print(f"Error: {e}")
    print(f"Row data causing the issue:\n{row}")
    return None

# Apply the create_sector_pie function
data['geometry'] = data.apply(create_sector_pie, axis=1)

# Filter out rows with None in the 'geometry' column
data = data.dropna(subset=['geometry'])

columns_to_convert = ['CSR', 'CELL_ID', 'SECTOR', 'MI_MYCOM_ID', 
'GENERATION', 'CELL_TYPE', 
                  'FDD', 'CELL_3G_CARRIER', 'EASTING', 'NORTHING', 
'GROUND_HEIGHT', 'AZIMUTH', 
                  'AREA', 'JV_ID', 'PCI', 'TAC', 'Band', 'BW', 
'Radius']


data[columns_to_convert] = data[columns_to_convert].astype(str)

#print(data.dtypes)

# Create a GeoDataFrame
gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(data, geometry='geometry')

gdf.crs = 'EPSG:27700'
# Define the output file path including the folder
tab_file = os.path.join(output_folder, 'N5_sectors.tab')

# Save the GeoDataFrame as a MapInfo TAB file
gdf.to_file(tab_file, driver='MapInfo File')
```
````

Please check above code and guide me how to fix it.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: What do you mean by "sometimes the code fails totally"? No error? And what means "it doesn't make the Pie correctly"? Your input is spatial data from a mobile network, verify if all sites have valid values for EASTING, NORTHING and AZIMUTH.